# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in struts hibernate application

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

I have deploy struts hibernate application into jboss , My jboss start without any error , But when i am trying to enter data to database by filling one form i am getting following error.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.viralpatel.contact.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    at net.viralpatel.contact.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at net.viralpatel.contact.view.ContactAction.<init>(ContactAction.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:494)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:350)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:119)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:150)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:109)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:288)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:388)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:187)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:478)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.CustomPrincipalValve.invoke(CustomPrincipalValve.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()Z
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.isTraceEnabled(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.<clinit>(NullableType.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.Hibernate.<clinit>(Hibernate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.<clinit>(TypeFactory.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1320)
    at net.viralpatel.contact.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 51 more
```

Comment: SLF4J strikes again! Looks like you have incompatible library versions for your logging framework. What tool are you using to build this app?

Comment: I am deploying application using apache ant version = apache-ant-1.8.1